# Is there a way to have a web page automatically play "multiple" mp3s?

Tags: mp3

I currently have a web page that, when opened, will play an mp3 file...

What I'd like to do is have it play through a list of mp3 files, automatically.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Generally, this is done with a Flash applet. I hear that playlist.com has a good one for that. :-P

Comment: Web pages that make noise are evil and need to die.

Comment: Whatever else you do, please make sure it has a large and immediately obvious mute button :)

Comment: No, it needs a large and immediately obvious START button!  Web pages shouldn't load and make noise automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What format are you using for your webpage?

Will this work:
http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/flash-mp3-howto.html